# how to add value of each element in firebase database list?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I am working on a hybrid application using ionic and angular, storing data to the firebase database using angularfire2

[image]

above is the image of the list in the firebase, now  i want to add **totalCalories** of each node in the list

this is my Code

```
 let count = 0;
 uList : Observable<any[]>;
 this.uList = this.dbServ.getConsumedFoodList(this.authServ.getUID()).snapshotChanges();
 this.uList.forEach(item => {
 item.forEach(itemData => {
      this.food = itemData.payload.val();
      console.log(this.food.totalCalories);
      count = count + this.food.totalCalories;
    })
  })
```

but nothing is getting in the count , it is giving 0 only.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up `uList` as an observable, and then never subscribing to it. Read up on [observables and subscriptions](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3), and you'll understand why your code isn't working. Basically, you are saying "*This is the data I will want to listen to*" but then you're never actually beginning to listen.

Unless you need constantly updating information on the client, I would recommend you skip using `.snapshotChanges()`... using that (*and subscribing to it*) is way overkill unless you really want real-time updates.... Instead, for simplicity, I would recommend that you pull the data using `.value('once')` something like:

```
let count = 0;
let uList = [];
let uid = this.authServ.getUID();

this.(AngularFireDatabaseVariable).database.ref(uid).once('value').then(dataReturnedAsObject => {
    uList = dataReturnedAsObject.val();

    uList.forEach(eachItem => {
        console.log(eachItem.totalCalories);
        count += eachItem.totalCalories;
    });

}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting data from database');
    console.log(err);
});
```

**Untested code*